# Month name to month number - 03 for Feb?

Tags: php, datetime, date, php-5.3, strtotime

I am trying to convert string month name to month number,

but why do I get **'03'** in the result for **'Feb'** in,

```
strtolower(date('m', strtotime('Feb')));
```

I tested with other month names and they seem to be fine,

```
strtolower(date('m', strtotime('Jan'))); // 01
strtolower(date('m', strtotime('Mar'))); // 03
```

What have done wrong?

Comment: because today is the 30th. Try adding '1st' to every string

Comment: Indeed: try `strtolower(date('m', strtotime('1 Feb')))`

Comment: You have not specified the day nor the year. And in any case you run into a problem with a specific PHP function, please first read the manual entry about it: http://php.net/strtotime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [php.net manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php):

> The function expects to be given a string containing an English date
>   format and will try to parse that format into a Unix timestamp (the
>   number of seconds since January 1 1970 00:00:00 UTC), *relative to the
>   timestamp given in now, or the current time if now is not supplied*.

This results in a mixture of todays date (January 30th) and "Feb" => February 30th - but this is not a valid date, so PHP returns the month number for March.

Trying something like

```
strtotime('01 Feb')
```

should solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Because today is Jan *30th*.  You are not supplying a day number so php assumes today's, ending up with Feb 30th. Which it then realises is not valid, so it goes on to Mar 2nd, poor confused thing.

Comment: 1 March, actually, since 29 February *does* exist this year.